# how to write mongoldb query for search/filter

Tags: mongodb

I want to filter input text from database and show that data.as shown in below I have tried these query $text query giving this working for text values but how to filter query for numeric fields like id or date.

```
find({$text :{$search:<input text>, $caseSensitive: false}})
```

I want output data which match with input text/value(which can be text, date,number).

Comment: Use find({"field-name":"value"})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB provides text indexes to support text search queries on string content. text indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements.

To perform text search queries, you must have a text index on your collection

```
db.stores.createIndex( { name: "text", description: "text" } )
```

You can use your search string with `$search` parameter :

```
db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee",$caseSensitive: false, } } )
```

Full documentation is available here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/

Comment: what about number and date type

Comment: MongoDB supports text search in Full text Search. You can search number and dates using that if those are stored as text. Otherwise, you will have to give the column names with regex in find() method.